# What is this item that came with my Cisco switch?

Tags: cisco, cisco-catalyst

We just received a new Cisco Catalyst 2960, and in the box came an item we've never seen before.  Interestingly enough, the documentation shows an image of the object, but it is not listed anywhere else in the guide (including the legend, which is numbered incorrectly)!

My buddies and I think it's some type of cable management device.  Can anyone identify and elaborate as to its proper use?

Here is an image from the getting started guide (with the object circled):

[image]

Comment: Very strange. I didn't get those with MY stack of 2960s.

Comment: After you get your answer you should contact Cisco and let them know the diagram is incorrectly labeled.  14, 15 and 16 in the diagram are 13, 14 and 15 in the legend.  This new part (probably a power cable securing device like @xeon said) was inserted and the legend never updated.

Comment: @Adrian Maybe ***you*** should have been nicer to your Cisco sales representative!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Looks like parts to hold the power cable into the switch.

Comment: That's it!  We took a look at the back of the switch and there are a couple of tangs to hold the metal piece in place.

Comment: Yep. It should hook somewhere behind the PSU a "grabs" the cable.

Comment: That'd be my guess as well - can you post a photo of the actual parts?

Comment: Unfortunately, no, since my workplace doesn't allow cameras.  Boo!  But if I happen to remember, I'll take it outside to my car and snap it with my phone.

Comment: The best workplaces don't allow cameras. Or cell phones. The really awesome ones make you change out of your street clothes.

Comment: @voretaq7 I suppose, it depends what you do at those workplaces.

Answer (score 23):

It's part of the power cable assembly. It serves two functions:

1. Mechanically hold the power cable in so it can not be accidentally pulled
2. Stress relief on the power plug itself, so the weight of the cable doesn't either loosen the connection or cause a short

I've seen this as standard equipment in all Juniper EX series switches, but the first time I've seen it on a Cisco. Also easier to install than a lot of other supports, since the support body screws on around the power cable.